# UIView Animation in Collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I make a custom UICollectionViewCell which is use to display BarChart graph. Now everything is working but I also want to put some animations. I want to put animations on dark green bars to animate but When I used animation code It's not working properly.

Here's the UICollectionView Xib Screen shot

[image]

Here's the photos of animation
staring like this
[image]

[image]

and complete the animation like this
[image]

**CollectionView cell class code**

```
class BarChartCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    //MARK: - OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var barChartTotalView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var barChartSpendAmountView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var barChartSpendAmountViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    class var identifier: String {
        "BarChartCollectionViewCell"
    }
    
    class var nibName: String {
        "BarChartCollectionViewCell"
    }
    
    var barChartValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let height = barChartTotalView.frame.size.height
        self.barChartSpendAmountViewHeight.constant = height * self.barChartValue

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        barChartTotalView.layer.cornerRadius = barChartTotalView.frame.size.width / 2
        barChartSpendAmountView.layer.cornerRadius = barChartSpendAmountView.frame.size.width / 2
        barChartTotalView.clipsToBounds = true
        
    }
    
    func configureCell(month: String,amount: Double) {
        self.monthLabel.text = String.LanguageStringFor(month)
        
        self.totalAmount.text = "QAR \(amount)"
        
        let percentage = amount / 190.0
        self.barChartValue = percentage
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
            self.barChartTotalView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Kindly tell me or suggest me how I can achieve my desired result Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to constant value before UIView.animate

```
self.barChartSpendAmountViewHeight.constant = height * self.barChartValue
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
           self.barChartTotalView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

Comment: not working already tried.